# how do I test a Java SIP client?

Tags: java, servlets, sip, asterisk, asteriskami

SIP programming looks much simpler than I originally thought:

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071781/java-web-development/sip-programming-for-the-java-developer.html

and

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss40/javadoc/jsr289/javax/servlet/sip/SipServlet.html

I would be interested in developing something along the lines of the Java World sample, but how do you test it?  I would like to test it against a hosted Asterisk PBX, but that seems expensive.

The only other option I can think of would be to deploy Asterisk, but that doesn't sound like much fun.

While I'm aware that there is, or will be, a Java API for the Asterisk Manager Interface, I'm interested in just plain-vanilla SIP.

Comment: Why not set up an Asterisk VM? [AsteriskNOW](http://www.asterisk.org/downloads/asterisknow) or [PBX in a Flash](http://pbxinaflash.net/) claim to be easy to set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I test a Java SIP client?

- If you have a SIP server in place then you try to register your
  client to the server by sending a SIP REGISTER message.
- If you don't have a SIP server in place, then use `SIPServlet` to
  create a basic server with at least a `doRegister` implementation. Once
  you have that, you can test a client with registration process.
- If you don't have both a client and a server. Then write a basic
  server using SIPServelt. You can use any SIP client(SIP soft phone)
  downloaded from internet to test your server.

Your questions is not very clear, hence I have provided the answer for different situations.

Comment: your answer is sufficient, at least until I find a better question to ask ;)

Comment: @JunedAhsan is there any `SIPServlet` implementation out there to just kick start rapidly ?

Comment: @YogeshSeralia Yes there are 1)https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19355-01/820-3007/gfmpq/index.html 2) https://jsip.java.net/